# Why is my inArray test always returning false?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Why is my inArray test always returning false whether the string is in the array or not?  I collect stuff from the form and joined two strings then put add them to the array.  I then check to see if the string I added is already there using inArray.  When I run the test I always get false.  What could I be doing wrong.  Here’s my code.

```
   $("#saveBtn").click(function () {


         for (var x = 0; x < checkedindex.length; x++) {
             var ind = checkedindex[x];

             var dateofclass = $(".TextBoxDate:eq(" + ind + ")");
             var timeofclass = $(".TextBoxTime:eq(" + ind + ")");
             var classday = $("select[name='searchString']:eq(" + ind + ")");

             classdate.push(dateofclass);
             classtime.push(timeofclass);
             dayofclass.push(classday);


             newDateAndTime = (dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString();
             var testString = (dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString();
             //check to see if this string is already in the array
             if (jQuery.inArray(testString, newDateAndTime) !== -1) //if element is not fond return -1.

                 alert("Yep");
             else alert("No");

         }

     });
```

Comment: Side note: `val` on jQuery instances will **always** return a string if the jQuery set has anything in it (`undefined` if the set is empty). So there's no reason for `(dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString()`; just `dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()` is fine (again, unless one of those sets may be empty, but I suspect you don't want to run that line if so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `testString` isn't an array. You either want to use `String#indexOf`:

```
if (testString.indexOf(newDateAndTime) !== -1) //if element is not fond return -1.

    alert("Yep");
else alert("No");
```

...or actually use an array:

```
newDateAndTime = (dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString();
var testString = [(dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString()];
// Note ---------^-----------------------------------------------------^
if (jQuery.inArray(testString, newDateAndTime) !== -1) //if element is not fond return -1.

    alert("Yep");
else alert("No");
```

Note that in the second case, you'll be looking in the array for a string that matches *exactly* (not a substring match).

Comment: You are right.  I'm using the first option.  Thank you very much!